# Are there some efficient ways to combine two loss functions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function

I am trying to optimize my model and tried several loss functions. I have three test datasets. The loss function MSE is the best in two of them, and loss function SNR is the best in another one (also SNR is not bad for the other two datasets, so does the MSE).

So I wonder if there is a way to combine the loss functions and get a ***global best***.

loss1=(-SNR)

loss2=mse

What I've tried:

loss = loss1 + 1000*loss2

loss = loss1 + loss2/(tf.stop_gradient(loss2/loss1)+eps)  (align loss2 to loss1)

loss  = loss1 + mean(log(square(error)))  (logarithm+logarithm)

But all of them didn't work for me. I would be very grateful if someone could give me guidance! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please define "global best"

Comment: I hope the model with a mixed loss function can achieve the best performance for all three datasets.

Comment: Your hope is not a definition. What is it mathematically? Sum? Product?

Comment: It's a denoising task in some kind of feature domain of audio, so I use the SNR improvement as the final goal. For example MSE achieved an improvement of 10,8,8 in dB for three datasets . And for SNR it is 8,10,10 in dB. So I wonder if mixing the loss functions can get a result like 11,11,11 in dB. If so, which could be a proper way and if not, I'd like to know if there are some other ways to improve this. I am new to deep learning so sry for the unprofessional explanation :)